# The difference of Prometheus / VictoriaMetrics on series_selector without time range

Tags: grafana, promql, victoriametrics

I have a metric query that calculates sum of the values for last d time range

```
sum(series_selector) - sum(series_selector offset d)
```

This works on PromQL since

- left side of the minus sign: sums all the value from the beginning
- right side of the minus sign: sums all the value from the beginning to d range before

So that result is sum of last d time range values.

Problem is that when I write the same query to the victoria metrics I get negative results.

I investigated the issue and solve it by using `sum(increase_pure(series_selector[d]))` function in victoria metrics which is the pretty much the same as the first code. However I want to know why in victoria metrics the first code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Both Prometheus and VictoriaMetrics can return negative values for the `sum(series_selector) - sum(series_selector offset d)` query in the following cases:

- If some time series matching the given `series_selector` stopped receiving new samples during the time duration `d`. Then `sum(series_selector)` will be smaller than `sum(series_selector offset d)` because the series value isn't included into `sum(series_selector)`, while it is included into `sum(series_selector offset d)`.
- If some time series matching the given `series_selector` have been reset to zero (aka [counter reset](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter)). In this case the value for this time series at `offset d` may be bigger than the value at the current time.

It is recommended using `increase(series_selector[d])` instead of `series_selector - (series_selector offset d)` because of the cases mentioned above. The [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function in VictoriaMetrics handles both cases in the most expected way. See [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) for more details.

Comment: increase() method in promQL assumes that counters starts from NO_DATA so that if new label created in d time range (value - NO_DATA) generated NO_DATA. So that increase() method does not work as expected. In MetricsQL increase_pure() solves my problem since it assumes that counters starts from 0. How can I achieve the same result in PromQL?

Comment: Also I couldn't quite get that `series_selector stopped receiving new samples`. Isn't that prometheus always should return all the counters itself has? (You can assume that I will never call counter reset)

Comment: Suppose you have a series selector `metric{deployment_id=~".+"}`. It matches time series `metric{deployment_id="foo"}` . This time series can be substituted with `metric{deployment_id="bar"}` after new deployment. After that the old time series with `{deployment_id="foo"}` stops receiving new samples, so it becomes invisible in queries covering time ranges after the new deployment.

Comment: sorry for late response. In my opinion "My actuator pushes the metrics about my service under the _monitoring/prometheus endpoint. After that prometheus scrap those metrics into its timebase database." So that I got confuse when you say "stops receiving new samples". Does labels removed when _monitoring/prometheus does not provide old metrics? If so, how counter works correctly after the deployment. Doesn't that should be reset after deployment?